# is there a way to upload multiple large image files to GCS in django admin?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, django-admin

I'm attempting to upload multiple image files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket simultaneously through the django admin interface, 14 image files totaling up to 175mb. They are contained in one model with multiple imagefields. I'm using django-storages to connect django to gcs.
I'm not able to increase the upload timeout past the 10 minute mark, and I have to stay inside the django admin interface. My project lead suggested that there might be a way to split the POST request into multiple smaller requests to circumnavigate the timeout, but I can't find any documentation on how to do such a thing inside django admin.

Clicking 'save' creates a POST request that takes over 10 minutes, which is long enough to give me a 413 error. I'm using google app engine as a back-end. When I use the local test server, it all uploads as intended. It takes a little while but not ten minutes. If I save after changing one or two images at a time it uploads successfully.

Comment: I think about using a back ground task queue like , celery, DjangoQ, django-rq etc.